# Adding and removing li by Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having left side pane and right side pane. I want to deal with two scenarios

1. When I click the list(li) on right side that want add on left side(`initially left side pane is empty) and remove from right side.
2. Reverse part of first one. When i click the added li in left side that need to be remove from the left side and added to the right side.

I did the first scenario like below

```
<div class="left_pane">
  <div class="content_left_pane">
    <ul data-role="listview" id="left_side_ul">
    </ul>
   </div>
 </div>

<div class="right_pane">
 <ul data-role="listview" id="right_side_ul">   
  <li class="showDetails" id="account-1" onclick="selected_destination($(this).attr('id'))">
    <div class="ui-grid-b">
       <div class="ui-block-a"><div>[Facility name] A</div><div>[Account]</div></div>
       <div class="ui-block-b"><div>[Address Line 1]</div><div>[Address Line 2]</div><div>[City],[Statte],[Zip code]</div></div>
       <div class="ui-block-c"><span class="ui-li-count" style="right: 30%; font-size: 15px;">12</span></div>
     </div>             
   </li>    
 </ul>
</div>



<script>
function selected_destination(id){   
      $("#right_side_ul li#"+id+"").clone().prependTo("div.content_left_pane ul#left_side_ul");
      $("#right_side_ul li#"+id+"").remove();
    }

  </script>
```

I don't have any clue to do the second part. Because in the first part i am sending the current li id in onclick function. But in the reverse part, in the left pane i am having ul only so i don't know how to  do the second scenario.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to not register onclick handler directly in html code. As you are using jQuery, this scenario should work for you:

HTML:

```
<div class="left_pane">
  <div class="content_left_pane">
    <ul data-role="listview" id="left_side_ul">
    </ul>
   </div>
 </div>

<div class="right_pane">
 <ul data-role="listview" id="right_side_ul">   
  <li class="showDetails" id="account-1">
    <div class="ui-grid-b">
       <div class="ui-block-a"><div>[Facility name] A</div><div>[Account]</div></div>
       <div class="ui-block-b"><div>[Address Line 1]</div><div>[Address Line 2]</div><div>[City],[Statte],[Zip code]</div></div>
       <div class="ui-block-c"><span class="ui-li-count" style="right: 30%; font-size: 15px;">12</span></div>
     </div>             
   </li>    
 </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#right_side_ul li').live('click', function(){
        $(this).appendTo('#left_side_ul');
    });

    $('#left_side_ul li').live('click', function(){
        $(this).appendTo('#right_side_ul');
    });
});​
```

Please note, that I'm using `live()` here because `LI` elements are dinamically added to the `UL`.

As you can see, javascript code for both right and left panes are almost the same, so you may optimize my solution by combining them into one

Comment: Just a pointer, but [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7. In 1.7, and later versions, use of [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is recommended instead. And in versions *earlier* than 1.7 [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) is recommended in preference to `live()`.

Comment: Thanks @aliona for your ripely. Now i understood the purpose of live().